# SPFx - How to install latest version of Office-UI-React for SPFx v1.0.2

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, spfx, sharepoint-framework, react

How to install latest version of Office-UI-React for SPFx v1.0.2 for On-Premise server?

With buildIn React version in SPfx framework v1.0.2 its all okay:
[image]

I can not use the latest version, what else to use as a framework like Office-UI-React

**This is error when installed last version of Office-UI-React:**
[image]

Any help, please?

Comment: What is the issue you are currently seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that newer versions of office-ui-fabric-react are incompatible with the typescript version required by spfx 1.0.2.

You can try this version, it should be supported.

```
npm -i office-ui-fabric-react@2.20.0 --save
```